# Gulp Unhandled stream error in pipe

Tags: gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

I have been using a gulpfile which, I have now modified to try and add sourcemaps to my compiled css and minified css files.

I have the following task in the file:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
return gulp.src('./src/sass/zebra.scss')

    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: autoprefixrBrowsers,
            cascade: false
        }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
});
```

However, when trying to compile, I get the following error:

```
stream.js:74
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the sourcemap file that's causing the problem.

When you do `sourcemaps.write('.')` you emit a `.map` file into the stream. That means you now have two files in your stream: a CSS file and a sourcemaps file.

When the CSS file reaches `cssnano()` it gets minified. However when the sourcemaps file reaches `cssnano()` that's when the error happens. `cssnano()` tries to parse the file as CSS, but since sourcemaps files aren't valid CSS files, this fails and `cssnano()` throws up.

You have to remove  the sourcemaps file from your stream after you have   persisted it to disk with `gulp.dest()`. You can use the [`gulp-filter`](http://npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) plugin for this:

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
   return gulp.src('./src/sass/zebra.scss')

    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: autoprefixrBrowsers,
            cascade: false
        }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination))
    .pipe(filter('**/*.css'))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
});
```

In the above `filter('**/*.css')` only lets the CSS file through, not the sourcemaps file, which fixes the problem.

I have also added a second `sourcemaps.write('.')` right before the end since you probably want sourcemaps for both the minified and unminified CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

If your running into pipeline errors, I found [this](https://medium.com/@boriscoder/catching-errors-on-gulp-js-4682eee2669f) to be very helpful

```
/**
 * Wrap gulp streams into fail-safe function for better error reporting
 * Usage:
 * gulp.task('less', wrapPipe(function(success, error) {
 *   return gulp.src('less/*.less')
 *    .pipe(less().on('error', error))
 *    .pipe(autoprefixer().on('error', error))
 *    .pipe(minifyCss().on('error', error))
 *    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
 * }));
 */
function wrapPipe(taskFn) {
  return function(done) {
    var onSuccess = function() {
      done();
    };
    var onError = function(err) {
      done(err);
    }
    var outStream = taskFn(onSuccess, onError);
    if(outStream && typeof outStream.on === 'function') {
      outStream.on('end', onSuccess);
    }
  }
}
```

If you wrap the task function with `wrapPipe` and put the `.on(`error`, error)` method on all your pipes like in the example above, it will copiously catch the error and point to the problem file, and line# generally.  No gutil needed.